# How to rename columns in a list according to their parent list name

Tags: r

My list is formatted as:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)
names <- c("T","U")
names(dfList) <- names
dfList
$T
  A B C
1 1 2 3

$U
  X Y Z
1 1 2 3
```

I would like to rename the second column using the name of the parent name in the list. For example:

```
[[1]]
  A T C
1 1 2 3

[[2]]
  X U Z
1 1 2 3
```

I have tried using lapply for this as follows:

```
dfList1 <- lapply(dfList, function(x) setNames(dfList[[x]],x))
```

Which produces:

```
[[1]]
  T NA NA
1 1 2 3

[[2]]
  U NA NA
1 1 2 3
```

I have also tried

```
dfList1 <- lapply(dfList, function(x) setNames(dfList[[x]][2],x))
```

Which correctly renames the second column, but removes the other columns:

```
[[1]]
   T
 1 2

[[2]]
  U
1 2
```

Am I on the right track or is this a dead end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
unname(Map(function(x, y) {names(x)[2] <- y; x}, dfList, names))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#  A T C
#1 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#  X U Z
#1 1 2 3
```

---

Or use `imap` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(dfList, ~ {nm1 <- .y
             .x  %>% 
               rename_with(~ nm1, 2)})
```

Comment: ``Map`` is the perfect solution. Is there anything specific about the problem that suggested the use of ``Map`` over ``lapply()``?

Comment: @NathanHaffner Regarding your question with `lapply`.  You can use `lapply` as well, but the issue is that you are going to name the second column based on the names of the list or the `names` object created.  One option is to loop over the sequence of the list, extract the list element with `[[` and the corresponding `names` as well.  With `Map`, you can have different inputs (assuming they are of the same unit length) and assign

Answer (score 2):

Something not very different from above, but usage of baseR's setNames here

- names of list (i.e. colnames of every list element collected in a vector say `nm`
- second element of `nm` changed to list name (.y argument in imap_*)
- colnames of all items of list (.x) changed as per `nm` using `setNames`

```
purrr::imap(dfList, ~ {nm <- names(.x)
 nm[2] <- .y
  setNames(.x, nm)})

$T
  A T C
1 1 2 3

$U
  X U Z
1 1 2 3
```